# Remove certain configuration options in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

Hi I would like to remove configuration options (download,zoom and pan) in plotly which appear when I hover over the plot. Imanaged to remove pan and zoom with

```
xaxis = list(fixedrange=TRUE),
             yaxis = list(fixedrange=TRUE))
```

but what about download?

```
    library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)%>%layout(title = "Incidents per Category",
           xaxis = list(fixedrange=TRUE),
           yaxis = list(fixedrange=TRUE))%>%
  config(toImage=F,sendDataToCloud=F)
```

I try to set these options to F but it does not work

```
[
  "zoom2d", "pan2d", "select2d", "lasso2d", "zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d", "autoScale2d", "resetScale2d",
  "hoverClosestCartesian", "hoverCompareCartesian",
  "zoom3d", "pan3d", "resetCameraDefault3d", "resetCameraLastSave3d", "hoverClosest3d",
  "orbitRotation", "tableRotation",
  "zoomInGeo", "zoomOutGeo", "resetGeo", "hoverClosestGeo",
  "toImage",
  "sendDataToCloud",
  "hoverClosestGl2d",
  "hoverClosestPie",
  "toggleHover",
  "resetViews",
  "toggleSpikelines",
  "resetViewMapbox"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using modeBarButtonsToRemove in config:

```
config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = list('toImage', 'sendDataToCloud'))
```

Is this what you had in mind?